# @ symbol in Drupal modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I'm trying to learn Drupal modules. Can someone tell me what the '@' symbol is? I dont remember coming across it in PHP. (Its tricky to search for it cos as far as I can tell, you cant google for symbols). Can I convert it into a normal PHP variable, modify it and finally put it back into an @ thing within the PHP of the .module file?

UPDATE: e.g.:

```
  $error['msg'] = t("We're sorry. We have now only @qty of the ....
```

in file...
http://drupal.org/project/uc_out_of_stock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While that is the case in general PHP, it is used differently in Drupal within the [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function.

You can properly use placeholders in your text (which should be wrapped in t() for translation purposes on i18n capabilities) by putting a @ , ! or % in front.

! = insert as is

@ = run text through check_plain

% = html escape text

[More info on the API page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7#comment-25348)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the @ symbol suppresses error messages.

There's plenty about it in the manual. When in doubt that's the place to go.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Yeah I know. Baffled me 1st time I came across it.

Comment: @SpaceBeers, I'm confused as teh error-control I thought had to be used before a function or variable. I've added an example to my question. I dont think '@qty' is either.